# How to place an android component offset from center?

Tags: android, xml, imageview, offset, centering

I want to place my imageview a little above the center. I have used centerHorizontal="true" along with paddingBottom , but it is placed in the absolute center. "padding" is not doing the work. What should i do?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    style="@style/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingBottom="300dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try with layout:margin_bottom .If not get what you want.Apply relativelayout and same bottom_margin.

Comment: I am using relative layout but still bottom_margin is not working.

Comment: ok.I can give you one more suggestion and that works for sure.But it is not an optimized way.It holds extra memory.Create a fake view that comes in center of your layout with visibility GONE.Now in your view that you want slight above the center put android:layout_above="@+id/id_of_invisible view_which_is_in_center_we_just_created".
Use this trick you will get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I created a frame layout inside the relative layout, positioned the imageview and then set the gravity to center.

Answer (score 1):

Could not find the exact answer but got an alternate way. I created a frame layout inside the relative layout, positioned the imageview in it and then set the gravity to center.
If there is any better solution please post.
My code:

```
Inside the relative layout--
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="800dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"

    >
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    style="@style/myImageView" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using the relative layout and not the linear or absolute layout.

Comment: Ya i am using relative layout.